# Efficient Dynamic word embeddings in TensorFlow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, word2vec

I was wondering where I should look to train a dynamic word2vec model in TensorFlow. That is, each word has a different embedding at each time-period (t). Basically, I am interested in tracking the dynamics of word meaning.

I am thinking of modifying the skip-gram word2vec objective but that there is also a "t" dimension which I need to sum over in the likelihood. Also, I have a l2 temporal regularizer on the word-embeddings in the likelihood function which *connects* the embeddings over time, so that the word embeddings evolve smoothly over time.

To give an example, think of the objective function on Page 14 of this paper (Section 3.2)(http://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/228927/228927.pdf), except that to make things simpler I have a l2 penalty instead of the non-differentiable l1

I can accomplish this in R, but it will not be able to scale. So, I am thinking of using TensorFlow (to which I am a newbie). So, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you do something in this direction? Care to share your findings? :